# how to chain multiple operations in js ternary operator

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator, chaining, operation, chain

in this case how to **chain two operations** if expression is true

```
a = 96
c = 0
a > 50 ? c += 1 && console.log('passed') : console.log('try more')
```

I tried chaining with && and it worked somehow in react, but not in node with vanilla js

Comment: Try to wrap the two conditions between && in parentheses

Answer (score 0):

Use the comma operator, and use parentheses to make sure everything is grouped.

```js
a = 96
c = 0
a > 50 ? (c += 1, console.log('passed')) : console.log('try more')
```

Answer (score 0):

`if-else` is preferred:

```js
a = 96
c = 0
a > 50 ? (c += 1) ? console.log('passed') : console.log('try more') : console.log('try more')

a = 46
c = 0
a > 50 ? (c += 1) ? console.log('passed') : console.log('try more') : console.log('try more')

a = 96
c = -1
a > 50 ? (c += 1) ? console.log('passed') : console.log('try more') : console.log('try more')
```